# SQL how create select with explicit return values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How do I select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT 11 AS Value UNION
 SELECT 24 AS Value UNION
 SELECT 53 AS Value UNION
 SELECT 124 AS Value UNION
 SELECT 2215 AS Value) AS ValueTable
```

This query give me a perfect result, just this query is ugly.

How create this just nicely such as:

```
select 11,24...
select arrray(22,24...)
```

These don't works just examples.

Thx

Comment: Each number should be on different row or one row with comma separated numbers?

Comment: What is wrong with your query? ***Ugly*** can be solve with beer goggles. What is your expected result?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: yes diferent row, its important. thx

Comment: if this is ugly for you. you should create table `ValueTable` with those values :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL split values to multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows) I dont think this one is more pretty. But is more generic and scalable.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is correct. The only thing I can do to make it pretty is remove all the field name declaration after the first one

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT 11 AS Value  UNION 
        SELECT 24  UNION 
        SELECT 53  UNION 
        SELECT 124 UNION 
        SELECT 2215) AS ValueTable
```

Comment: This is awesome putting lipstick on a pig. +1  ... you don't get paid enough around here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option like this you propose, because it is usual to have separate data from logic:

```
/* Data */  
CREATE TABLE ValueTable (Value INT);
INSERT INTO ValueTable (Value) VALUES (11), (24), (53), (124), (2215);

/* Logical */
SELECT * FROM ValueTable;
```

Comment: whatever you do don't do this for small data. DDL calls take too long.